# n log n and computer speed

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose that a computer can solve a problem of size 1000 in time t.  Suppose further that the problem has a nlgn complexity. If we purchase a computer which can run at twice the speed, what is the approximate size of the problem that we could solve in t time?

can anyone tell me the answer for this and the explanation

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is high school algebra, not computer science. If 1000 log 1000 = t, what n will have n log n = 2t?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let v be initial computer speed. Let k be problem size on the new computer. Then we have this equation:

```
1000 * ln(1000) / v = k * ln(k) / (2 * v)
```

Solving it yields k ~= 1834

Comment: Thanx alot brother, but how did you solve after reaching 
2000 * ln(1000) = k * ln(k)

Comment: I just used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2000+*+ln%281000%29+%3D+k+*+ln%28k%29) (click 'Approximate form' in the Solution box).